# Is there any other option to display DMS grid and graticule in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

Is there any other option to display DMS grid and graticule in QGIS Print Composer, since there is no plugins available yet?

Answer (score 14):

There is possibility to do it in Print Composer now. Also it is possible to simply manually create vector layer with grid in QGIS (Vector->Research Tools->Vector Grid) - the only way if more grids are needed in one frame (update: from QGIS 2.6 it is possible to do more grids for frames).

In Composer Manager select map frame and go to Item Properties / Grid

[image]

Comment: Is there an option to put the grid inside the frame of the map? At the moment the grid adds to the size of the map. That causes trouble when I need the finished product to be a specific size.

Comment: @Johanna anotation (numbers) can be either inside or outside frame - can be set under "Draw coordinates" for every side. Talking about grid frame - you can make easily map window a bit smaller if you need bigger frame, it is not that hard to calculate the right numbers and fill exact values for both map frame size and position + frame size to fit your needed dimensions.

Comment: thank you. I didn't investigate those options closely enough because I didn't want CRS type labels on the grid.  And yes, I had already calculated the size of my output to allow for a 3mm bleed by the printers. I had hoped that there was a way that I didn't need to calculate again.