# Creating custom coordinate grid using QGIS

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I am using QGIS `2.14.2`.

I want to create a custom grid different from latitude / longitude, with letters and numbers on the axes.

X = A, B, C, D, E, ...
Y = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **2** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **4** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **5** |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** | **E** |

I also intend to serve to use the data in an overview in the print the composer to give the location of the map, `A - 1`, or `C - 5`, etc.)

Answer (score 10):

In the print composer, create three grids on your map item:

- one for the actual grid lines
- one for X values (to disable grid lines, set them to "No pen")
- one for Y values (idem)

For Y coordinates, you want to see 1 2 3 4 ...
Depending on your max and min coordinates, and interval, use the **Custom** format in the **Draw coordinates** submenu. You can add an offset to show the values in the middle of the grid lines. The `@grid_number` variable represents the value of the X and Y at the grid's position.

For example, if your coordinates start at 49.5 and have an interval of 0.25, you can write  `(@grid_number - 49.5) / 0.25 + 0.5` in the Custom field.

For X values, you want to see A B C D E.
You do the same but you take a substring of the alphabet.
It also depends on your bounds.
`substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST', (@grid_number - 2.5) / 0.5 + 0.5, 1)`

I don't know if it's possible to automatically retrieve the X_max, Y_max and interval values in variables to avoid hardcoding them.

Here is an example for Belgium where both lat/long and ABC/123 coordinates are shown:

[image: Belgium]

I've uploaded the sample qgs project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/du5qz4aqz16zhfe/grid.zip?dl=0) if you want to have a look at it.