# Print composer: Draw coordinates in right format and language

Tags: qgis, print-composer

When drawing the coordinates of a map in WGS84 in decimal format, they appear in "German", which means they look like 81.3°O (O for "Ost" which means "East" in German). I am using a German version, but need them in English, indicating "E" and "N".

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: You can either change the _Locale_ setting of QGIS to English (`Settings > Options > Locale`) or create a **custom** coordinate format with an expression which adds the coordinates and the string "E" or "N" at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to create a custom formate, but I guess I don't use the right expression. Do you know which expression to use?

Comment: I've posted a possible solution =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

- Change the **Locale** setting of QGIS to English

  ```
  Settings > Options > Locale
  ```
- Or create a **custom coordinate format** with an expression which adds the coordinates and the string "E" or "N" at the end. You can do this by adding a grid to the composer:

  [image: Adding grid to composer]

  And then selecting the `Custom` coordinate, clicking the `ε` expression button and using an expression like:

  ```
  (@grid_number +10) || ' N'
  ```

  [image: Custom coordinate format]

  You can find out how to calculate the relevant values for the grid coordinates from this post: [How to create a custom coordinate grid in the QGIS 2.14.2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195293/how-to-create-a-custom-coordinate-grid-in-the-qgis-2-14-2)

Comment: Thank you. That worked well. I customized the grids with the expression. Now it looks good.

Comment: @Eva - Most welcome, glad it worked :)