# QGIS Print Layout Grid Reference Numeric Format

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

Using QGIS3.14
The default style of grid labels is single size digits, e.g. 251000E and 5897000N.
I wish to show the grid labels in a format similar to Ordnance Survey with the 51 of the easting and the 97 of the northing in a larger size.
Can this be done within the Print Layout Grid properties or is there a plugin to achieve this?

Comment: Please review https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213099/print-composer-draw-coordinates-in-right-format-and-language

Comment: @Mapperz that question refers to locale / number formats - here OP needs to change text formats for *part* of a number.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186271/print-composer-custom-grid-label-problem or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28870/add-utm-labels-to-grid-in-qgis

Comment: Check this https://youtu.be/kM-aAgFdPbI may be it is what are you looking for

Comment: The solutions suggested show it is not a simple matter to format the coordinates this way.  I won't proceed to implement the format, but suggested solutions are appreciated.