# How to share custom coordinate in an atlas between pages?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, atlas

I know we can build custom coordinate grid (cf. url:[How to create a custom coordinate grid in the QGIS 2.14.2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195293/how-to-create-a-custom-coordinate-grid-in-the-qgis-2-14-2/)).

I would like to use this in an atlas but I have not succeded yet.

I get

Page 1 :
ABCDEF
1     
2
3
4

Page 2 :
ABCDEF
1
2
3
4

While I would like to have a continuity in letter from page 1 to 2 :

Expected Page 2 :
GHIJKL
1
2
3
4

Any idea how to proceed?