# QGIS Map Composer frame to show numbers and letters

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I'm trying to create a tactical burn plan map using QGIS. 3.10.3. It needs to be able to be used by lay people to communicate where features are on the map.

To do so I need the map frame to show letters across the top and bottom and numerals on the left and right sides such as in this image.

[image]

I've worked out how to add a grid and zebra frame (see below).
How do I display the numbers and letters?

[image]

Comment: This was often discussed and answered in here, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/195297/87346 for example or more tutorial like here: https://kartoza.com/en/blog/create-a-custom-reference-grid-in-qgis-composer/

Comment: That looks good - I'll work through it now. I really struggled to find an answer when I searched.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't test with Qgis 3.10 which is pretty old.

I will take the assumption that the grid interval is 100 meters.

In the map grid properties, check "Draw coordinates", set "Format" to Custom and enter this expression :

```
if ( @grid_axis = 'x' ,
 char(64 + ceil((@grid_number-x_min(@map_extent )) / 100 )),
ceil((y_max(@map_extent ) - @grid_number) / 100 )
)
```

[image]

Change both 100 according to your grid interval.

The labels will be aligned with grid lines. To apply an offset to the line, edit the line style, set the offset parameter to "Map Units" and add an offset of the half of your grid interval (50 in this case).

[image: line style]

Here the result :

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you! Where do I add the expression?

Comment: @Tamar : click the button with Epsilon symbol, at the right of the format option (I added a screenshot in my answer)