# Listing features and their respective map grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I am trying to list map features and the Reference Grid they fall into. The grid is setup in the Print Composer as a 50mmx50mm grid over a 400mmx400mm map with Cells Labeled as 1A, 1B, etc.. I didn't make the Grid as a spatial layer. Is there a way to list the features and the cell they can be found in referencing the Grid directly or do I have to recreate it as a spatial layer? If it has to be a spatial layer then is there an easy way to export the composer grid to a spatial format?

Comment: see my answer to [this similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/183323/55203) - note the plugin I wrote hasn't been ported to QGIS3

Comment: Well I wish I knew about that plugin for my work around. I basically made a grid as shapefile and rotated it to match my composer grid, my map has a rotation as well, then iterated over each square selecting by location and adding the Cell name to the Grid Ref field. However because my map was rotated I had to rotate the grid shapefile to match, which it doesn't exactly close but not exactly. A grid export option would be nice but I still have not found it.