# Setting grid in QGIS that automatically adjust its intervals?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layouts, grids-graticules

I am setting a template for multiple maps in QGIS 3 Layout and i was wondering if there is a way of automatically adjusting the grid's interval as a function of the scale of the map?

I did a bit of research here:

- [Is there any other option to display DMS grid and graticule in QGIS Print Composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31200/is-there-any-other-option-to-display-dms-grid-and-graticule-in-qgis-print-compos)
- [How to create a reference grid in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183323/how-to-create-a-reference-grid-in-qgis-print-composer)

but they seem not to answer my question.

I want to make sure that no matter the scale of my map, this template adjusts the grid. Currently, one grid may work well for a determined scale

[image]

But the grid may get quite dense if i zoom out (see numbers in the top as well)

[image]

Or useless if i zoom in

[image]

I want to define the intervals in a way that they are automatically updated as a function of the scale of the map.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting your 'Interval' to 'Fit Segment Width' in map grid properties. This will keep your grid to a defined spacing, and accommodate different scales.

Answer (score 1):

With Qgis 3.X it's possible.
Edit the value and use the `@map_scale` property.

[image]